# Create new boolean fields based on specific terms appearing in a tokenized pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, boolean

Looping over a list of terms to search for, I need to create a boolean field for each term according to whether or not it is present in a tokenized pandas series.

List of search terms:

```
terms = ['innovative', 'data', 'rf']
```

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'job_description': [['innovative', 'data', 'science'],
                                            ['scientist', 'have', 'a', 'masters'],
                                            ['database', 'rf', 'innovative'],
                                            ['sciencedata', 'data', 'performance']]})
```

Desired output for df:

```
                     job_description  innovative   data     rf
0        [innovative, data, science]        True   True  False
1      [scientist, have, a, masters]       False  False  False
2         [database, rf, innovative]        True  False   True
3  [sciencedata, data, performance]        False   True  False
```

Criteria:

1. *Only exact matches should be replaced* (for example, flagging for 'rf' should return `True` for 'rf' but `False` for 'pe**rf**ormance')
2. each search term should get it's own field and be concatenated to the original df

What I've tried:
Failed, as it creates a boolean for each term in the series:

```
df['innovative'] = df['job_description'].explode().str.contains(r'innovative').groupby(level=-1).agg(list)
```

Failed:

```
df['innovative'] = df['job_description'].str.contains('innovative').astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

Failed:

```
df.loc[df['job_description'].str.contains(terms)] = 1
```

Failed: I tried implementing what was documented here ([See if item in each row of pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750493/see-if-item-in-each-row-of-pandas-series)), but could not adapt it to create new fields or flag properly

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can use a nested list comprehension to evaluate if each term exists in each row and assign the list to columns in `df`:

```
df[terms] = [[any(w==term for w in lst) for term in terms] for lst in df['job_description']]
```

Output:

```
                    job_description  innovative   data     rf
0       [innovative, data, science]        True   True  False
1     [scientist, have, a, masters]       False  False  False
2        [database, rf, innovative]        True  False   True
3  [sciencedata, data, performance]       False   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty fast:

```
e = df['job_description'].explode()
new_df[terms] = pd.concat([e.eq(t).rename(t) for t in terms], axis=1).groupby(level=0).any()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                    job_description  innovative   data     rf
0       [innovative, data, science]        True   True  False
1     [scientist, have, a, masters]       False  False  False
2        [database, rf, innovative]        True  False   True
3  [sciencedata, data, performance]       False   True  False
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Seems like 'e' is not defined: NameError: name 'e' is not defined.  Should that be something else?

Comment: Oops, yep! Mistake on my part. Check the answer now ;)

Comment: Beautiful. Works very fast, indeed, and thanks for the updated. Defining 'e' did the trick, and I just had to create a new_df = pd.DataFrame before that, and it worked great. Many thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe This should be much faster than the list comp for your data. You should accept this one instead imo

Comment: @richardec, I will definitely test! It's a shame that I can't flag both answers as solving the problem, but I will test both and flag accordingly depending on speed (got to test against a list 125 terms long and 14,000 records in a dataframe.

Comment: @John sorry to bug you, but I updated this solution a bit. For me, it doubled the speed.

Comment: @richardec not bugging me at all! I really appreciate the help and am testing now. My initial run was indeed very fast. Will test your update now. Related question (I'm newly active on Stack): is it proper form to accept the FIRST answer you get or the BEST answer you get? Thinking it's probably the best?

Comment: @John the proper form is to accept whichever one you want, probably the one you're using :)

Comment: @richarddec Accidently deleted last comment. Against a 2270 deep dataframe, and using a 90-long terms list, your first solution took 6.05sec. The faster version took 4.25sec, but the list comprehension approach took 2.46sec.  Many thanks again for the help today!